# AMQP - Asynchronous RPC - futures to return a value results in 'unexpected return value'

Tags: java, spring, asynchronous, rabbitmq, amqp

I would like to perform asynchronous communication in RPC-style. I am using AMQP RabbitMQ for this purpose: I am sending my message using `AsyncRabbitTemplate`, defining return type as a `List` of `myObj` type, and setting a `callback` to handle the reply or failure case, so far no problems. The problem is in the following: I want to return my reply, but the IDE is saying "unexpected return value".

```
public List<myObj> call()
{
    AsyncRabbitTemplate.RabbitConverterFuture<List<myObj>> future = asyncRabbitTemplate.convertSendAndReceive(message.getBytes());

    future.addCallback(
            reply -> { return reply; } // <-- "unexpected return value"
            t -> System.out.println(t.getMessage());
    );
}
```

What is wrong? How do I interpret this message? Is something wrong conceptually?

Comment: success callback is a consumer not a supplier.Here [Success Callback](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/util/concurrent/SuccessCallback.html)

Comment: sorry but it's not quite clear to me how rewriting of my functionality should look like with that information... i'm a bit green to this

Comment: ```future.addCallback( reply -> {  System.out.print(reply); },
    t ->  { System.out.println(t.getMessage()); }
  );```

Comment: what do I do if I want to return the reply from a callback? (to complete the function signature)

Comment: use ```ListenableFuture<?> future = asyncRabbitTemplate.convertSendAndReceive(message.getBytes());``` and invoke ```future.get()``` as described here [Async Reference](https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/reference/html/_reference.html). But this is as good as synchronous req/reply, take a call on that.

Comment: The link you provided says `You can either synchronously retrieve the result later, by invoking get() on the future, or you can register a callback which will be called asynchronously with the result.`. If I would like to return the reply without any blocking communication, what is the implication for my case? in other words, I want to maintain asynchronous behaviour

Comment: you can return Future as method return type instead of calling ```future.get()``` yourself.```Future<List<?>> call() ```. Technically you are not calling it but HandlerMethodReturnValueHandler will handle it for you.

Comment: unfortunately, it's not desirable to change `List<myObj>` signature. Is there an alternative which does not involve changing method signature?

Comment: you can still go with ```ListenableFuture and invoke future.get()```

Comment: The thread handling `future.get()` will remain waiting for it to complete (blocked)? I would like non-blocking behaviour.

Comment: Thats what I am trying to explain. you need to change the return type anyways to support future otherwise you cant unless you use reactor patterns like webflux or rxjava.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186732/discussion-between-zeruno-and-barath).